# Como fazer o Postgres criar um arquivo para povoar um banco?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, tabela-html

Tenho um banco no POSTGRESQL povoado , queria  saber se existe um comando

SQL que retorne um aqruivo  que tivesse o seguinte comando para todas as tabelas existentes:

```
INSERT INTO aluno(id , nome, idade ) values(1,'Raul',23)
```

Queria fazer isso para povoar um outro banco que possui dados similares ao banco antigo , porem possui novas tabelas!

Comment: Só para ver se entendi, você precisa que seja gerado um arquivo com os comando SQL's de inserção dos dados já cadastrados em suas tabelas antigas para poder adicioná-los a tabelas novas porém com a mesma estrutura?

Comment: Se for isso, veja se esse link te ajuda http://www.guj.com.br/t/postgresql-gerar-script-de-um-banco-populado-resolvido/291383/3

Comment: Essas tabelas novas estão criadas em qual banco? É PostgreSQL também

Comment: É um outro banco, no  PostgresSQL tambem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para gerar os comandos `insert` dos dados que contém no banco você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

Selecionar o formato Plain

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na aba Dump Options 1, marcar "Data"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na aba Dump Options 2, marcar "User Insert Commands"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sugiro utilizar o notepad++ para abrir

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, sua resposta parece estar certa mas não consigo ver os dados no notepad++ , uso a versao 7.2 e o PGadmin  9.6. Qual versao do PGAdmin você usa?

Comment: Você selecionou o tipo de dados "Plain"? Uso o postgresql 9.5 e pgAdmin 3. Mas acredito que o formato que você usou não é "Plain"

Comment: @Deu bronca porque eu usava o  postgresql 9.6  e o pgAdmin 3! Mas vou installar a versao 9.5! Essa versao 9.6 veio com o pgAdmin masi lento e uma interface estranha !!Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o utilitário pg_dump:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html